# How to display a custom content on a map marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to implements a google map which display some markers, and I would like to implement a code that allows me to show a custom content (a web page) when I click on each marker... I searched on the net and I found this code:

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var markers = [];
    function initialize() {
        
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.502686, 10.03658),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"), mapOptions);
    
    
            var locations = [
                ['point1', 35.502686, 11.050228, 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png'],

                ['point2', 36.083198, 9.370759, 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png']

            ];
        
    
            var marker, i;

 var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
      'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
      'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
      'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
      '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
      'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
      'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
      'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
      'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
      'Heritage Site.</p>'+
      '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
      'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
      '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: contentString
});
    
    
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.close();
            });
    
    
            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map,
                    icon: locations[i][3]
                });
    
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
        
                markers.push(marker);
            }
    
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        
        function myClick(id){
            google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
        }
</script>
<div id="googlemap" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="myClick(0);">Open Info Window</a>
```

But this only enables me to show "point1" or "point2"

Any idea how to resolve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding, you doing a lot more to accomplish the task. I did the same using the following JavaScript function. Give it a try:

```
function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = { zoom: 2, center: centerLatLang, scrollwheel: false, draggable: isDraggable, panControl: true }; //preparing the options for map
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);           //preparing the map

        var marker_image = '<?php echo $base_url . '/' . $path; ?>/images/AD_Map_Pin_small.png'; //take this inside the for loop if you want different marker
        var prev_infowindow =false;
        <?php $abc = 0; foreach(map_details() as $map_data) { ?>
            var latLang<?php echo $abc; ?> = new google.maps.LatLng<?php echo $map_data['field_coordinates_value'];?>;
            var content<?php echo $abc; ?> = "<div class='InfoMarker'><?php echo '<img src='.$base_url .'/' .$map_data['field_image'].'><h3>'.$map_data['title'].'</h3>' . $map_data['field_copy']; ?></div>";
            var infoWindow<?php echo $abc; ?> = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: content<?php echo $abc; ?>});
            var marker<?php echo $abc; ?> = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latLang<?php echo $abc; ?>, map: map, icon: marker_image });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker<?php echo $abc; ?>, 'click', function(){ if(prev_infowindow) {prev_infowindow.close(); }  prev_infowindow =infoWindow<?php echo $abc; ?>; infoWindow<?php echo $abc; ?>.open(map, marker<?php echo $abc; ?>);});
        <?php $abc++; } ?>
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you explain when it stopped working? @user2389313

Answer (score 0):

When you execute:

```
infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
```

you are setting the content of the infowindow to the passed text. Since the first element of your locations array is 'point1' or 'point2', that's what you are setting the InfoWindow content to.

If, for example, you want to display `contentString`, then use:

```
infowindow.setContent(contentString);
```

Comment: Well, it works, but what if I want to display an external php file instead of the "contentString" value and passing a parameter?
exemple: infowindow.setContent(page.php?dd=2);
is this correct?

Comment: You would need to get the content using Ajax.